# d3 Rickshaw Graph Disable Hover effect

Tags: coffeescript, d3.js

I'm using Rickshaw with d3. I would like to show the x axis value when I'm hovering over a bar on the bar graph, but I would like to disable to hover effect that shows the series type and the y axis value.

Is there a way to only display one and not the other? I tried doing this and it doesn't work (i'm compiling this coffeescript to javascript):

```
hoverDict =
  graph: graph
  xFormatter: (x) ->
    today = new Date()
    today.setDate(today.getDate()- x + 1)
    return today.toDateString()
  yFormatter: null
hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail(hoverDict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to edit rickshaw.css for the .item.active field:

```
.rickshaw_graph .detail .item.active {
opacity: 1;
display:none;
}
```

Making display:none will make the yFormatter not display.